# knockoutjs observablearray not displayed

Tags: knockout.js

I'm learning Knockoutjs and have a doubt how to display the values ​​of a observablearray ();

my JS code in:

```
<script>

        function Cliente(nome, CGC) {
            this.Nome = nome;
            this.Cgccfo = CGC;

        };

        function ordemservicoVM() {
            self = this;                   
            self.pessoas = ko.observableArray([
                new Cliente("ValueOne", "ValueTwo")               
            ]);            
        };

 $(document).ready(function () {           

            ko.applyBindings(new ordemservicoVM());
}

</script>
```

Html Code:

```
<table>    
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>CGC</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: pessoas" >
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Nome"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Cgccfo"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

already used the same structure as the above code, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: You said it worked perfectly, and it does. What is your question?

Comment: @Tyrsius - other code worked perfectly, but not in the example above

Comment: @JulioCes No, it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/FD43K/

Comment: thnks @PaulManzotti , i checked console debug and found erros in my script. I was not using the debug tool in my browser. Thus any error not perform perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing parenthesis after $(document).ready function. Corrected fragment below. Notice the last line difference:

```
$(document).ready(function () {           
    ko.applyBindings(new ordemservicoVM());
});
```

After I added parenthesis your code started to work fine.

It was actually showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" error in console of chrome development tools. So keep your eye on a console to catch such issues.